# Ошибка при подключении модуля vuex-persist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Есть такой модуль:
[vuex-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist#features)
Подключение производил следуюшим образом:

1) добавил код в nuxt-config.js 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) добавил код в созданный файл в `plagins/vuex-persist.js`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее после этих манипуляций у меня возникло уведомление о уязвимости в модулях и рекомендовалось обновить это с помощью команды `npm audit fix`:
Данную команду выполнил.

После этого всего на разных страницах проекта вылетает вот такая ошибка:

```
SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"
    restoreState index.js:201
    plugin index.js:223
    default vuex-persist.js:5
    NuxtJS 3
        nuxtReady
        nuxtReady
        mount
    VueJS 2
        nextTick
        flushCallbacks
client.js:84
    errorHandler NuxtJS
    VueJS 4
        globalHandleError
        handleError
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это уже вторая попытка устоновить этот модуль на бекап проекта.
Во время первой попытки после таких же манипуляций с установкой - какое то время ошибок не было
и локальное хранилище подхватывало автоматом vuex.
Потом после написания пару строк кода для локального хранилища вылетела такая же ошибка как и в данный момент.

Вопрос:
Почему это происходит, что я упускаю из виду и как это лечится?